# Angular2 component view not updating when variable changes

Tags: data-binding, angular, components

I have a simple component that just renders a progress bar.

It initializes fine and the progress passes over to it just fine, but the template is not updating with the new values.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector : 'progress-bar',
  template : `
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div>{{currentProgress}}</div>
      <div [style.width.%]="currentProgress" class="progress"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    '.progress-container {width: 100%; height: 5px}',
    '.progress {background-color: #8BC34A; height:5px}'
  ]
})

export class ProgressBar {
  currentProgress: number;

  constructor() {
    this.currentProgress = 0;
  }

  onProgress(progress: number) {
    console.log(progress) //consoles correct percentages
    this.currentProgress = progress;
  }

  reset() {
    console.log(this.currentProgress) //is 100
    this.currentProgress = 0;
  }
}
~
```

Elsewhere

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpFileService.progress$.subscribe((progress: number) => this.onProgress(progress));
  }

  onProgress(progress: number) {
    this.progressBar.onProgress(progress*100);
  }
```

I feel like I am missing something very remedial.

Comment: If you'll update your question to show me how `onProgress` is being called, I can probably make my answer more helpful for you - I suspect there's a deeper anti-pattern in use here.

Comment: Added the onProgress part. It's retrieved through an xhr onprogress that I subscribe to.

Comment: I was right :-) Just a sec and I'll update

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're going about this in a way that's working against the framework, and going to lead to much wailing and gnashing of teeth.

Right now, you're manually subscribing to an observable -  `httpFileService.progress$` - and then manually updating a property on a child `ProgressBar` component, bypassing angular's change detection mechanism - which is why the UI isn't updating. You *could* manually fire change detection after setting this property and the UI would update as expected - but again, you'd be working against the framework, so let's look at how to work with it instead:

I assume that "elsewhere" is a parent of your `ProgressBar` component - let's call that `ElsewhereComponent`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'elsewhere',
  directives: [ProgressBar],
  template: ` 
    <div>
      <progress-bar [currentProgress]="httpFileService.progress$"></progress-bar>
    </div>  
   `
})
class ElsewhereComponent { 
  // you can remove the ngOnInit and onProgress functions you posted
  // you also don't need a reference to the child ProgressBar component
  // ... whatever else you have in this class ...
}
```

The most important thing to note here is the addition of `[currentProgress]` on the `progress-bar` component: This is telling angular that there is an input property named `currentProgress` on that component that should be bound to `httpFileService.progress$`.

But you have now lied to angular - as it stands,`ProgressBar` has no inputs at all, and angular will tell you about it when it tries to bind this nonexistent property to the given value. So we need to add the input property, and the preferred way of doing that is with the [`Input()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html) decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector : 'progress-bar',
  pipes: [AsyncPipe]  //import this from angular2/core
  template : `
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div>{{currentProgress | async}}</div>
      <div [style.width.%]="currentProgress | async" class="progress"></div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ProgressBar {
  @Input() currentProgress: Observable<number>;
  ...
  constructor(){ 
     // remove the line you have in here now
  }

}
```

There are two critical differences here to note: First, `@Input()` tells angular that `currentProgress` is an input property. We've also changed the type of that property from `number` to `Observable<number>` - this isn't strictly necessary, but it's useful because it allows the second critical difference:

[`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AsyncPipe-class.html) has been added to the component's `pipes`, and used in both of its template bindings to `currentProgress`. This is useful because it tells angular to handle all the dirtywork of subscribing to the Observable and updating the UI each time it emits a new value.

And that's all it takes: Both the width of the bar and the text above it will now update automatically to reflect the values emitted from your `httpFileService`, and you didn't have to write a single line of 
imperative code to make it happen.

Comment: I implement the above, but the issue I am facing is the progress bar is not updated automatically. However, if I click on the bar, it works good. the bar will display the current value from the observables. Any idea?

Comment: @Hammer what you describe is a change-detection problem

Comment: Yes. Agree, but i compare the codes with u shared here without any clue.. i paste my code here, appreciate if u can help take a look? Tks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046757/ui-is-not-updated-automatically-when-value-is-available-from-the-observable